# ObjectDataSource with ControlParameter missing from query in ProcessPostData - why?

Tags: asp.net

I asked this on forums.asp.net but haven't gotten any traction, so I'm trying again here.

I have a GridView/ObjectDataSource listing page that is supporting some filter functionality.  Further/detail operations are filtered on those selected inputs.  One of the things put on the detail row is a drop-down to change an object's state; that drop-down has a server-side on changed handler defined.  The problem is that it's not working.  From what I can see it looks like the reason it's not working is that the hidden field that holds the filter option is not being recognized during the ProcessPostData() part of the page lifecycle.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" TypeName="WDB" ID="odsCases" 
             SelectMethod="GetRows" >     
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter Name="sID" ControlID="SelectedCaseID" PropertyName="Value"/>
         <asp:Parameter name="MaxRows" DefaultValue="0"  />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

with the select method being

```
public List<SearchResult> GetRows(String sID, int MaxRows)
{
    return SearchHelper(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sID) ? " WHERE S.ID=" + sID : String.Empty, false, false, MaxRows);
}
```

Obviously the select method doesn't show much, but it's a pretty general sql statement used for both the listing page and the detail page.  The data source is above, and the hidden field is SelectedCaseID, which is populated with the specific row id when someone enters any of the various filter criteria and clicks Search.

I've verified that it's filled in correctly and the detail row is displayed correctly, but when someone changes the drop-down on the detail row, I put breakpoints in GetRows() and found that it gets called in the ProcessPostData() phase - except without the SelectedCaseID parameter, so obviously the controls and data don't match up to the viewstate of the form as it was rendered.  And the action selected and the event on the value change don't get fired.

GetRows() gets called again in the same page request on the PreRenderData() phase, only this time it does have the SelectedCaseID value, so the detail page renders as one would expect - except that that drop-down action you chose isn't getting executed.

Any ideas why the ControlParameter wouldn't be set properly in the ProcessPostData() phase?  I do know with Fiddler that the field is being posted back properly; it's just not available when it's trying to do ProcessPostData().

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by pushing the call up a level and adding String.IsNullOrEmpty(sID) ? HttpContext.Current.Request["SelectedCaseVID"] : sID to compensate, but I'd really like to understand why the ControlParameter isn't working on the pre-load ProcessPostData()

Comment: Appears that there are 2 causes:

1) The hidden field was declared after the GridView in aspx.  The first ProcessPostData() appears to rehydrate controls in decl order, so the GridView comes first, the SelectMethod is called and the ControlParameter hasn't been rehydrated yet, so I get null.

2) The other parameter (row count) was getting initialized in the OnLoad event handler - except when ProcessPostData() comes before OnLoad, it hasn't been initialized yet so it's 0.

I moved the hidden fields above the GridView and moved the other initialization to OnInit and things start working.